# Recursively build XML from PSQL Result Set (using PHP)

Tags: php, xml, postgresql, recursion

I am building an XML document successfully with the following code:

```
public function build($result) {

    $root = $this->append(new xmlElement('data'));
    $root->append(new xmlElement('collection'));

    while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){

        foreach($row as $fieldname => $fieldvalue){
          $second = $root->append(new xmlElement($fieldname));
          $second->write($fieldvalue);
         // $seconds_child = $second->append(new xmlElement('second child child'));
         // $seconds_child->write("second's child content");
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, what is the best way to do this recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$current = $root;
foreach($row as $fieldname => $fieldvalue) {
    $next = $current->append(new xmlElement($fieldname));
    $current->write($fieldvalue);
    $current = $next;
}
```

I have a feeling that object-reference reassignment will mess this up; if it doesn't work let me know.